# How to make a program using c# to pronounce word by word based on audio specified that stored in the database?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, audio

I want to make a program that will produce audio continuously which will pronounce the corresponding word. My problem is, why my other button cannot function when the audio is played? Is there any other alternative to solve this problem? Below is my code for the program.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using mshtml;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Media;


   namespace MalayVersion
  {
      public partial class MalayVersion : Form
     {
       //SpeechSynthesizer reader; //declare the object 
    System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();

    public MalayVersion()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

          //this.player.LoadCompleted += new     AsyncCompletedEventHandler(player_LoadCompleted);

        // ---  pronounce word from txtWord  ---
        //connect to database - microsoft access  -- DONE
        //looking for the words  -- DONE
        //take path for the word  -- DONE
        //open file (path)  -- DONE
        //play audio - open file from path(database), read!  -- DONE
    }

    private void MalayVersion_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnStop.Enabled=false;
        webBrowser1.Navigate(txtAddress.Text);
    }

    //btnExit
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }

       private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }

    private void btnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //progressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
        //progressBar1.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 30;
        webBrowser1.Navigate(txtAddress.Text);
    }

    // ----  segment the text  ----
    //paragraphs to sentences : find punctuation marks   -- DONE
    //sentences to words : find blank space  -- DONE
    //convert everything into readable text -- DONE

    string GetTextRange()
    {
        if (webBrowser1.Document != null)
        {
            IHTMLDocument2 document = webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument as IHTMLDocument2;
            if (document != null)
            {
                IHTMLBodyElement bodyElement = document.body as IHTMLBodyElement;
                if (bodyElement != null)
                {
                    IHTMLTxtRange range = bodyElement.createTextRange();

                    if (range != null)
                    {
                        return range.text;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    void GetSentence()
    {
        string source = webBrowser1.DocumentText;

        string[] stringSeparators = { "@", "<p>", "</p>", ".", ":", "\r", "\n", "\t", "?", "!", "<br>", "\"" };
        string[] result;

        result = source.Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        // Return total elements of the array
        int ttl = result.Length;

        for (int i = 0; i < ttl; i++)
        {
            txtSentence.Text = result[i] ;
            //MessageBox.Show(result[i]);
            GetWord();
        }
    }

    public static string NumberToWords(int number)
    {
        if (number == 0)
            return "kosong";

        if (number < 0)
            return "negatif " + NumberToWords(Math.Abs(number));

        string words = "";

        if ((number / 1000000) > 0)
        {
            words += NumberToWords(number / 1000000) + " juta ";
            number %= 1000000;
        }

        if ((number / 1000) > 0)
        {
            words += NumberToWords(number / 1000) + " ribu ";
            number %= 1000;
        }

        if ((number / 100) > 0)
        {
            words += NumberToWords(number / 100) + " ratus ";
            number %= 100;
        }

        if (number > 0)
        {
            if (words != "")
                words += "dan ";

            var unitsMap = new[] { "kosong", "satu", "dua", "tiga", "empat", "lima", "enam", "tujuh", "lapan", "sembilan", "sepuluh", "sebelas", "dua belas", "tiga belas", "empat belas", "lima belas", "enam belas", "tujuh belas", "lapan belas", "sembilan belas" };
            var tensMap = new[] { "kosong", "sepuluh", "dua puluh", "tiga puluh", "empat puluh", "lima puluh", "enam puluh", "tujuh puluh", "lapan puluh", "sembilan puluh" };

            if (number < 20)
                words += unitsMap[number];
            else
            {
                words += tensMap[number / 10];
                if ((number % 10) > 0)
                    words += " " + unitsMap[number % 10];
            }
        }

        return words;
    }

    void GetWord()
    {
        string[] delimiterChars = new string[] { " " };

        string sentence;

        if (txtSentence.Text != "")
        {
            sentence = txtSentence.Text;

            string[] words = sentence.Split(delimiterChars,
                 StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

             int countWord = words.Length;
            //string[] words = sentence.Split(delimiterChars);

             for (int i = 0; i < countWord; i++)
             {
                 lblWord.Text = words[i];

                 Int32 intValue;
                 if (Int32.TryParse(words[i], out intValue))
                 {
                     int numVal = Convert.ToInt32(words[i]);
                     string str = NumberToWords(numVal);

                     lblWord.Text = str;                         
                     ReadWord();
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     lblWord.Text = words[i];
                     //MessageBox.Show(words[i]);
                     ReadWord();
                 }
             }
        }
    }

    void ReadWord()
    {
        if (txtSentence.Text != "")    //if text area is not empty 
        {
          /*
           * search word from lblWord.Text in db
           * after found the word, take path for that word in path col
           * open audio file
           * read the word
          */

            //set up the connection string
            string ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\MalayVersion\MalayDict.accdb";
            //set up the select statement
            string SelectCommand = "SELECT path FROM Word where word = '" + lblWord.Text + "'";
            //set up the connection object&nbsp;using the conn string
            OleDbConnection Connection = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString);
            //set up the data adapter using the select statement and the connection object
            OleDbDataAdapter Adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(SelectCommand, Connection);
            //a new empty dataset
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            //fill the dataset with a new datatable of all the results
            Adapter.Fill(ds, "Word");//string is the DataTable name, can be anything
            //now, let "Table" point to the datatable with our results
            DataTable Table = ds.Tables["Word"];
            //get the path into string
            String strPath = "";
            strPath = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["path"].ToString();  

            //System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();
            player.SoundLocation = strPath; 
            player.Load();
            player.PlaySync();  

            /* reader = new SpeechSynthesizer();
             reader.Speak(lblWord.Text);
             //reader.SpeakAsync(lblWord.Text);
             reader.SpeakCompleted += new EventHandler<SpeakCompletedEventArgs>(reader_SpeakCompleted); */
        }
    }

    private void btnRead_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //GetTextRange();
        btnStop.Enabled = true;
        GetSentence();
    }

    private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        player.Stop();
    }

    private void btnPause_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         //player.pause();
       }

     }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing everything on the "GUI thread" if you want your GUI to remain active, you need to palm some of the work (like playing audio) off to background/worker threads.

This might be a good place to start: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Comment: i don't really get what are you trying to tell me. can you please elaborate more? tq.